# animation doesn't function properly in play-mode Unity V2020.2.7f 3/16

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to have triggered animation going up>rotate>up

I've been watch this video about "setting up animation to triggers"(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJiO4cvsHAo&t=382s) and I did everything the video said to do which work for the first then when I load up the next then it started happening.
[This is the animator/animation trigger setup I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rreig.png)

What expected mostly was the animation would play up>rotate>up but instead it just Up part nothing else in play-mode, when I tried in inspector-mode it just plays the animation as intended.

What I've also tried was making new animation and rewriting same code that I used to if that would help but doesn't then I realized that it has something to do with the animation or something with Unity play-mode so I thought using updated unity(2020.2.6-2020.2.7) to see if that would help but it didn't.
Here's the code I used for animation trigger controller

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PG_animationV3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    
  [SerializeField] 
  private Animator Pg = null;

   [SerializeField] 
   private bool Pg_anim_trigger = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool Pg_anim_trigger_down = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
      if (Pg_anim_trigger) 
      {
          Pg.Play("PG_animatorcs",0 ,0 );
      } 
      else if (Pg_anim_trigger_down)
      {
          Pg.Play("PG_animatoipnv2anim", 0 ,0 );
      }      


    }


}
```

**_________________________________________________________________________**

Here's the video to show what I mean https://youtu.be/PsCplNXYnhw

3/10/21- So I figured it out I just had to put the cube under a parent with the animation

but now it says Animator.GotoState:State could not be found and the cube doesn't show here's the video https://youtu.be/kIPJ_-P2CJo

Cam animation work fine I just had to do that because something play-mode or animation
**_______________________________________________________________** Update/3/11/21

I forgot too add `gameObject.setactive(false);` and set parent animator controller to none and Now I need to  set timer and set player speed to 0 zero it doesn't bug out. Here's the code of for the player movement

```
public class Player_controls : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    GameObject Player;
    
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public Vector3 po;
  
   public float forwardMovement = 1050f;
    public float sidewayMovement = 660f;
    public float Jumpmovement = 5.01f;
    public float Speed = 50;
    
    
   

       void OntriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Power-up"))
         {
             forwardMovement = 0;
         }
        }
    public void FixedUpdate()


    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardMovement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

**___________________________________________________________**

Comment: Do you have your animations properly setup and your animation transitions and all that?

Comment: @RazvanS. Yes, I made sure they work

Comment: @RazvanS. I'll show in video form

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? In your video I don't see a door or anything connected to the video which you've shared as a source.

Comment: @hardartcore what the video was showing is for trigger animation through objects. and what I'm trying to achive is that the player will play the animation when trigger so it can go to the next/expand level

Comment: So you want to play an animation when the player collide with another object or area?

Comment: @hardartcore yes but it works inspector mode not play-mode even though everything works fine

Comment: What you're trying to do is pretty weird. So in the hardcoded animations you are changing the cube's position and then in PlayMode you're trying to make the cube jump and also animate. I suggest doing all that from code. In case you want to stick with animations don't change any position besides the y from code. Also you should have some transitions between your animations in the controller and trigger them by using event variables.

Comment: @RazvanS.  it more gravity affect than jumping

Comment: @RazvanS. I re did the animation an now it works but all I need to do now is to set player movement to zero

Answer (score 0):

You can't have hardcoded coordinates in animations (like changing x,y,z inside of the animation) and then also change those from code. Unity doesn't know what to do in that situation.
The animation says that y should grow from (just random examples) 2.1 to 5.3 but the code (gravity) says it should be 6.2. So you either have to ONLY change Y in the animation (NOT X,Z) and change X,Z in code or forget about the animation all-together and just do everything in code.

Or you can have your animated cube inside of a parent GameObject, perform all your actions on the parent GameObject (like moving) and have your child cube GameObject perform the animations in local coordinates.